# Compare files with each other within the same directory

Tags: bash, shell, diff

We have 20 files named as `file*.txt` all in one directory:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
...
file20.txt
```

In the same directory we have other files too, which we need to ignore:

```
someotherfile.csv
somemore.txt
etc.pdf
```

Need to find out if the contents of the files are the same. Tried to use `diff`, obviously failed:

```
diff -r ./file*.txt ./file*.txt`
```

Comment: If you just want a quick "are the same" answer, I'd use `md5sum file*.txt`. What answer do you need exactly? Do you need it in a shell script? Do you want to know what file differs?

Comment: @Mathias could you post your comment as an answer, this solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: The normal form of file comparison with `diff` is `diff -uNb oldfile newfile` The options `-b` and `-w` control how much whitespace difference is ignored. The option `-r` controls recursive behavior. You can also use `--label name` to give a consistent name in the diff header information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a quick visual "are the same" answer, I'd use;

```
md5sum file*.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

A relatively simple one-liner might suffice:

Tested on OSX,

```
md5 -q file*.txt | sort -u
```

If you see more than one line as output, the files are not the same

Answer (score 0):

If you are just comparing two files, then try:

```
diff "$source_file" "$dest_file" # without -q
```

or

```
cmp "$source_file" "$dest_file" # without -s
```

in order to see the supposed differences.

You can also try md5sum:

```
md5sum "$source_file" "$dest_file"
```

If any suggestions please do reply...!

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in the directory which has `file*.txt` and run

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=./file*.txt
for filename in $FILES; do
    for other in $FILES; do
        if [ "$filename" != "$other" ]
        then
            cmp -s $filename $other
            retval=$?
            if [ $retval -eq 0 ]
            then
                echo "$filename $other are same"
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

And it will print both `file1.txt file3.txt are same` and `file3.txt file1.txt are same`. You can figure out how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Linux seems to have a different set of tools on board than OSX. The above (md5) looks nice, but doesn't work, as `md5` is `md5sum` and returns the file name of the checked file on each line.

My version on RH linux:

Create equal files first:

```
for i in `seq -w 1 20` ; do echo one > test${i}.txt ; done
```

Then run this:

```
md5sum *.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sort -u
```

With a `| wc -l` or something, you could find the number of lines. I'd personally go this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum * | sort -r | uniq -d -w 5
```

will list all duplicates, but not triplicates and so on.